# I want to call a Servlet as a very first file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to call a `Servlet` as a very first file to execute like welcome file.

In this servlet I am retrieving data from database and rendering it to display page at a  very first page.

what I need is when I run program

**either**

> url should be-`http://localhost:8083/projectName/servletUrl`
>
> not `http://localhost:8083/projectName/`

**or**

> if url is `http://localhost:8083/projectName` this should hit my `servlet(/servletUrl)` not `welcome file`.

Comment: why dont you configure the url of the servlet as welcome file ?

Comment: @Manmay how to do.for now  
I am using `@WebServlet("/")` in my servlet still `index.jsppage` is being called.

Comment: Have you tried my proposal with web.xml?

Comment: I am using Annotation,defining in `web.xml` works  only in case when `index.jsp` is not in `web-content` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your servlet URLpattern as `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml` file located in `WEB-INF` folder of webapp like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>ProjectName</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>ServletURLpattern</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Assuming you use eclipse as IDE and `servlet version 3 or 3.1` than you have to create `web.xml` manually.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this file `WebContent`->`WEB-INF`->`lib`->`web.xml`.

> It will only be visible if you have ticked the Generate web.xml deployment descriptor while creating the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"    
version="3.1">
<display-name>Database_Conn</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>ServletURLpattern</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what If we not select this file to generate,then how call to servlets will resolve?Is this necessary to generate `web.xml`?

Comment: This file automatically gets generated, but you won't be able to see it if you don not tick that option. These files gets executed by default.
    index.html,index.htm,index.jsp,default.html,default.htm,default.jsp,

Answer (score 0):

I have used such servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The key part is URL pattern that matches all possible URLs unless you add another servlet-mapping for other servlets.

Comment: I am using `@WebServlet("/")` in my servlet still `index.jsp`page is being called.

Comment: I would try configure the servlet inside web.xml - just to be sure. What conatiner do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <servlet>  
       <servlet-name>PenServlet</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>com.sun.PenServlet</servlet-class>  
       <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>
```

> Here load-on-startup is an attribute of web.xml that will loaded first
>   if it has a lowest Integer Number.for example if you have 3 servlet that
>   is mentioned in the web.xml like

```
    <servlet>  
       <servlet-name>PenServlet1</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>com.sun.PenServlet1</servlet-class>  
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>
    <servlet>  
       <servlet-name>PenServlet0</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>com.sun.PenServlet0</servlet-class>  
       <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>
    <servlet>  
       <servlet-name>PenServlet2</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>com.sun.PenServlet2</servlet-class>  
       <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>
```

> Here then load-on-startup 0 is loaded first in your web application
>           then 1 and 2 and so on..
>           you need to use this to get data and set it to your first page or return
>           your page from servlet with loaded data.

Comment: loading the servlet doesnot mean to executing this before any file.

Comment: `<load-on-startup>` is only for loading any servlet at the time of deployment not to execute or call its service method.